# I use grid layout but the final result is not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

I have encountered a problem with the grid layout that I am using.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
<title>Grid training</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">
        <h1>This is the title</h1>
        <h3>This is the</br>lorem ispum doler sis amet</h3>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="cta">
    </div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;700;900&display=swap');

*{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

.container{
padding-top: 50px;
width: 95%;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr;
grid-gap: 15px;
}


 .container > div{
height: 90vh;
}

.image{
background-image: url("img1.jpg");
background-size: cover;
}

.text{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 65%;
margin-left: 50px;

}

.text h1{
margin: 50px 0;
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 85px;
}

.text h3{
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 35px;
}

.cat{
border-radius: 25px;
border-style: none;
font-size: 28px;
width: 150px;
height: 40px;
margin-top: 95px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px)
{
.container{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    width: 95%;
}

.image{
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
}
```

However, the image on the right side is not responsive when I minimize the browser.
For this reason, I used media queries. Is this technique correct or is there an easier method?
Is there anything else I should consider about the code and make it responsive?

Answer (score 1):

The idea you have going is correct, but I recommend for you to design first to mobile size then create media queries for your desktop sizes and tablet sizes etc. But, looking at your media query for phone size you do not need to declare a width size, and you need to make sure to include display:grid; in that class as well. You do not need class text and class image, when you declare the main class container and you say that it has two columns by writing grid-template-comlumns is set to 1fr 1fr then any new div inside there will be the new column and it i wll just add more rows the more divs you add.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <title>Grid training</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- if you choose to have this class text the class itself would only be for things like padding other than that it is not necessary--> 
        <div>
            <h1>This is the title</h1>
            <h3>This is the</br>lorem ispum doler sis amet</h3>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="cta">
        </div>
        <img src ="" />
        <!-- as you can see the first div you have with h1 and h3 will be one piece in column 1 and then the img section will be another piece in column 2--> 
    </div>
```

css:

```
    *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    }
    
    /* i would make it first mobile */
    .container{
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 3px; 
    }
    
     .container > div{
    height: 90vh;
    }
    
    img{ 
    width: 90%
    }

    .image{
    background-image: url("img1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    }
   
    .text h1{
    margin: 50px 0;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 85px;
    }
    
    .text h3{
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 35px;
    }
    
    /* i think you mean cta */
    .cat{
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-style: none;
    font-size: 28px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 95px;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 900px)
    {
    .container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-column-gap: 15px;

    }
    
    .image{
        width: 95%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*"responsive"* can mean different things and you need to specify exactly what you want.

For the `.image` div, you are using a `background-image`, which means the image used is not setting the size of the `<div>`. If you want the content (the image) to set the size and the ratio of the `<div>`, the simplest solution is to use `<img>` tag instead of `background-image`:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;700;900&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  padding: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.text {
  border: 50px solid #ccc;
  padding: 50px 35% 50px 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.text h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 85px;
}

.text h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.cat {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-style: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 95px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 'image' 'text';
  }
  .image {
    margin: 0;
    grid-area: image;
  }
  .text {
    grid-area: text;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .text {
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
  <title>Grid training</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>This is the title</h1>
      <h3>This is the<br>lorem ispum dolor sit amet</h3>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="cta">
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If, on the contrary, you want the image to fill its container and get cropped on either direction (depending on whether the container is landscape or portrait), you could keep `background-image` and use `background-size: cover`, while also centering it in the div (to make sure it gets cropped equally):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;700;900&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  padding: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  min-height: 100vh
}

.image {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/600/400) center /cover;
}

.text {
  border: 50px solid #ccc;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-right: 35%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.text h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 85px;
}

.text h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.cat {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-style: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 95px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 'image' 'text';
  }
  .image {
    margin: 0;
    grid-area: image;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
  }
  .text {
    grid-area: text;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .text {
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
  <title>Grid training</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>This is the title</h1>
      <h3>This is the<br>lorem ispum dolor sit amet</h3>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="cta">
    </div>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Side note (it's killing me): it's "***dolor sit** amet*", not *"doler sis"*.